# Study the convergence of the following series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+3} \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to study the convergence of the following series:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^2+3} \sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}) $

Is a positive series, so I should divide for $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$ 
and then use the comparison test ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With *equivalents*, as it's a series with positive terms:
\begin{align*}\frac n{n^2+3}&\sim_\infty\frac1n,\quad \sin\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\sim_\infty\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}\sim_\infty\frac1{\sqrt n}, \\\text{hence}\quad\frac n{n^2+3}\sin\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}&\sim_\infty\frac 1{n^{3/2}},\quad\text{which converges.}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

By the Taylor series expansion, as $u \to 0$, one has
$$
\sin u=u+o(u^2)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)\times \frac{n}{(n^2+3)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\times \frac{n}{(n^2+3)}+O\left( \frac{1}{n+2}\times \frac{n}{(n^2+3)}\right)
$$ or
$$
\sin\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)\times \frac{n}{(n^2+3)}=\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}+O\left( \frac{1}{n^2}\right)
$$ and the initial series is **convergent**.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

Note that we have for $n\ge 1$

$$0<  \sin \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}\right)\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

Then use the comparison test on $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$.

Comment: Why was this vote reversed?

Comment: I liked both answers, but I'm just a student  and from my perspective the other one seemed more complete to me. Thanks anyway for your prompt answer